# In jQuery how do I find elements if they contain the attribute, regardless of its value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

In jQuery, I can look up an element with a specific data attribute value like so ...

```
$(myElt).find(`[data-slide='${current}']`)
```

but how would I lookup elements based on whether it contains the "data-slide" attributes, regardless of what the "data-slide" values are set to be?

Comment: `'[data-slide]'` https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write:

```
$(myElt).find(`[data-slide]`);
```

Comment: This is an **often** repeated duplicate question, there's no need to answer it, just find the dupetarget.